# Code a website builder using PHP and JQUERY

Tags: php, builder

I am looking for suggestions, references, articles that can help me understand as how to create a website builder. My users will choose a template and then edit in the editor similar to WIX.com I am interested to offer them a platform with similar features.

If there is any article or resource available that can give me an idea as what are the pros and cons of the application.

Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

This question doesn't exactly belong here but
I've built a website builder and here's the gist;

**It's going to take a long time**

You're describing an application that's going to take a long time to make.
A website builder is not a small application it's going to have a lot of features in order to stand out and compete with the website builders that are already in place.

**You're going to have to either have a team or be good at coding yourself**

This application will need to follow an architecture like MVC to be able to properly perform maintenance on your application and to keep extending it's functionallity.
You're either going to need to be good at PHP, SQL, JS and JQuery and have a lot of time on your hands or have a team to get this done with the right skill sets.

**No place to walk you through**

The complexity of this application would also be very high and there is no document or video that will walk you through building the entire application simply because of it's complexity.
You're going to have to come up with how to build this application yourself.

If you're going to want to be doing this make sure you're prepared and have the resources to do so, this is not just a simple little project.